# SQL Error number #1215 - Cannot add foreign key

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I keep getting this error in my script when I run it on phpMyAdmin.

```
     #1215 - Cannot add foreign key constraint
```

It appears on this table only where I have two foreign keys.

```
     CREATE TABLE WORK_LOG (
     ORD_ID             INT(4),
     EMP_ID             INT(4),
     HOUR_SLOT          NUMERIC(2),
     EMP_COMMENT        VARCHAR(255),
     CONSTRAINT WORK_LOG_FOREIGN_KEY_ODR_ID FOREIGN KEY (ORD_ID) REFERENCES WORK_ORDER (ORD_ID),
     CONSTRAINT WORK_LOG_FOREIGN_KEY_EMP_ID FOREIGN KEY (EMP_ID) REFERENCES EMPLOYEES (EMP_ID));
```

Here are the tables that I have used in this section, thought it might be useful in finding the issue.

```
     CREATE TABLE WORK_ORDER (
     ORD_ID             INT(4) AUTO_INCREMENT,
     CLI_ID             INT(4),
     ORD_DOI            DATE,
     APPROVED           BOOLEAN,
     DESCRIP            VARCHAR(255),
     COST_TYPE          BOOLEAN,
     TOTAL_COST         NUMERIC(10,2),
     ORD_CONDITIONS     VARCHAR(255),
     ORD_COMMENTS       VARCHAR(255),
     CONSTRAINT WORK_ORDER_PRIMARY_KEY_ORD_ID PRIMARY KEY (ORD_ID),
     CONSTRAINT WORK_ORDER_FOREIGN_KEY_CLI_ID FOREIGN KEY (CLI_ID) REFERENCES CLIENTS (CLI_ID),
     CONSTRAINT ORD_ZERO CHECK (ORD_ID > 0));
     ALTER TABLE WORK_ORDER AUTO_INCREMENT=1001;

     CREATE TABLE WORK_LOG (
     ORD_ID             INT(4),
     EMP_ID             INT(4),
     HOUR_SLOT          NUMERIC(2),
     EMP_COMMENT        VARCHAR(255),
     CONSTRAINT WORK_LOG_FOREIGN_KEY_ORD_ID FOREIGN KEY (ORD_ID) REFERENCES WORK_ORDER (ORD_ID),
     CONSTRAINT WORK_LOG_FOREIGN_KEY_EMP_ID FOREIGN KEY (EMP_ID) REFERENCES EMPLOYEES (EMP_ID));

     CREATE TABLE EMPLOYEES (
     EMP_ID             INT(4) AUTO_INCREMENT,
     EMP_NAME           VARCHAR(255),
     EMP_LOC            VARCHAR(255),
     PHONE_NO           NUMERIC(11),
     BILLING_RATE       NUMERIC(10,2),
     PAY_RATE           NUMERIC(10,2),
     CONSTRAINT EMPLOYEES_PRIMARY_KEY_EMP_ID PRIMARY KEY (EMP_ID),
     CONSTRAINT EMP_ZERO CHECK (EMP_ID > 0));
     ALTER TABLE EMPLOYEES AUTO_INCREMENT=1001;
```

Hopefully somebody can help me with this!

Thanks

Comment: Do you add the tables in the order shown? Because `Employees` probably needs to exist before being referenced.

Comment: its always the most obvious thing! thanks for your help! I feel like an idiot now haha

Comment: This question was caused by a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers.

Answer (score 1):

Your order of table creation must be like below. Make sure that table `EMPLOYEES` and `WORK_ORDER` has been created before `WORK_LOG` since table `WORK_LOG` references both of them. See a successful Demo here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/36348b

```
 CREATE TABLE EMPLOYEES (
 EMP_ID             INT(4) AUTO_INCREMENT,
 EMP_NAME           VARCHAR(255),
 EMP_LOC            VARCHAR(255),
 PHONE_NO           NUMERIC(11),
 BILLING_RATE       NUMERIC(10,2),
 PAY_RATE           NUMERIC(10,2),
 CONSTRAINT EMPLOYEES_PRIMARY_KEY_EMP_ID PRIMARY KEY (EMP_ID),
 CONSTRAINT EMP_ZERO CHECK (EMP_ID > 0));


CREATE TABLE WORK_ORDER (
     ORD_ID             INT(4) AUTO_INCREMENT,
     CLI_ID             INT(4),
     ORD_DOI            DATE,
     APPROVED           BOOLEAN,
     DESCRIP            VARCHAR(255),
     COST_TYPE          BOOLEAN,
     TOTAL_COST         NUMERIC(10,2),
     ORD_CONDITIONS     VARCHAR(255),
     ORD_COMMENTS       VARCHAR(255),
     CONSTRAINT WORK_ORDER_PRIMARY_KEY_ORD_ID PRIMARY KEY (ORD_ID),       
     CONSTRAINT ORD_ZERO CHECK (ORD_ID > 0));


 CREATE TABLE WORK_LOG (
 ORD_ID             INT(4),
 EMP_ID             INT(4),
 HOUR_SLOT          NUMERIC(2),
 EMP_COMMENT        VARCHAR(255),
 CONSTRAINT WORK_LOG_FOREIGN_KEY_ORD_ID FOREIGN KEY (ORD_ID) 
 REFERENCES WORK_ORDER (ORD_ID),
 CONSTRAINT WORK_LOG_FOREIGN_KEY_EMP_ID FOREIGN KEY (EMP_ID) 
 REFERENCES EMPLOYEES (EMP_ID));
```